# My imported eclipse project gives error the project was not build since the build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.object

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-project-template

i have imported a existing project to eclipse but it gives errors for java files only i have set libraries i have also set window>preferences>installed jres.BUt the problem is not solved. The error message is the project was not build since the build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.object. Fix the error.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4upHD.png)

Answer (score 0):

right click on project -> properties ->java build path -> libraries -> add library choose JRE system library and pick workspace default JRE , also check your SDK path windows -> preferences -> android and browse your SDK location then restart eclipse

Comment: I have already did this project -> properties ->java build path -> libraries -> add library choose JRE system library and pick workspace default JRE but iam getting the same error but for sdk i cant find Android option in window > preferences screenshot

Comment: If you can't see it too you 're missing the whole android plugin